# Calculating average raster value for area in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst

I have Raster data for a country which has Evaporation Data in its pixels. I also have Vector layer which has the 30 cities of the country.

What I need is the average Evaporation value of each city from the raster data using ArcGIS?

I have access to the spatial analyst extension.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know the Raster Toolset in ArcGIS? Do you have access to the spatial analyst extension? You may read about and try PointToRaster first.

Comment: I have access to the spatial analyst extension

Comment: please send me the steps

Answer (score 9):

Try to use [Zonal statistic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) (or [Zonal statistic as table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) if you want to have table as an output) tool with parameter MEAN if your cities are polygons. If your cities are point, you could make [Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000019000000) around them and then use Zonal statistic.

Comment: the Cities layer i have is polygons

Comment: please  send me the steps

Comment: You could use Help pages (see answer above) to understand the functions. Use your cities as zones and your raster as a value.

Comment: if i have daily raster images for these cities for one years..should i have repeat this steps for each image,or there is a way to help me to calculate the avarage  daily evaporation for each city in one step to get 365  MEAN ET value for each city

Comment: That is subjective question, I don't know what you need. If you need daily ET results, you have to do it for each day. But i.e. if you need mean ET for whole year, you could make average ET for whole year from daily rasters and then make zonal statistic.

Comment: If I want to build model in ArcGIS for daily ET results, for each day .to run it once, I mean the input of the model will be folder of  365 raster images and the out put will be also 365 results. How can I do this?

Comment: Please ask it as a separate question.