# ArcMap - Spatial Join with Raster and Vectorial files

Tags: raster, arcmap, vector, spatial-join

I have two layers, a raster (arr_ker) and a vector (Polygon), as can be seen below:

[image]

In ArcMap, I need to add the raster data to each of the entities found in Polygon. It would be ideal as an average.

Is that possible?

I was investigating with "Spatial Join", but it only accepts to combine vector values.

Comment: Does this help? ... https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/how-do-i-assign-average-raster-values-to-polygons/td-p/12428

or this:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180358/calculating-average-raster-value-for-area-in-arcgis-desktop

Does this answer your question? [Calculating average raster value for area in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180358/calculating-average-raster-value-for-area-in-arcgis-desktop)

or any of the others at this web search? ... https://www.google.com/search?q=polygon+raster+average+arcgis

Comment: Do you have the Spatial Analyst extension? If not Zonal Statistics is not an option so you will need to vectorize your raster with Raster to Polygon then perform a spatial join; Raster to Polygon only works for integer rasters, the raster appears to be classified in the image so, hopefully, this is a viable workaround.